# Fixing Make on Raspbian install, or linking to precompiled copy of V4L driver

Tags: make

Familiar with what Make does, but this is an impressive list of issues to resolve with little understanding of how it does it. Might anyone else be able to assist with what needs doing to resolve all these errors, and/or link to a guide that I can follow?

Alternatively, in the short term, if anyone knows where I can obtain a V4L driver I could use with Raspbian, that would also be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Usually raspbian should have included v4l since around 2013, could you check it with lsmod?

Comment: also you seem to try to compile the driver from 11 years old sources

Comment: @mashuptwice - I have no doubt it is included in Raspbian, however I am pursuing a troubleshooting path based on VLC crashing when trying to load /dev/video0 with errors about frame size being different to what is expected. The first advise I got was to update the driver, which I trust also eliminates corrupted files for that driver as a potential cause. The first article I found on how to do that stated to download this source - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3yXQHhFG7M . I am also curious how you knew the source was 11 years old?

Comment: Because you are using the source of [v4l-dvb](https://github.com/OpenStbV4l-dvb/v4l-dvb), which wasn't updated since 11 years ago. The youtube video is also 10 years old

Comment: Compiling a driver should **not** be the first step when troubleshooting. How are you trying to get vlc to read from the capture device?

Comment: @mashuptwice - Pointing it to /dev/video0 under Media -> Open Capture device, trying all of the source options. Happy to be advised on how to troubleshoot this problem, but as for v4l-dvb, is there a more recent replacement to it that I could use?